# IIS rewrite rules to modify the url

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Following is the sample url:

```
http://localhost/myapp/images/Loading/bandwidth_States.png
```

which I want to rewrite to:

```
http://localhost/myapp/images/Loading/bandwidth_States.png?ver=20131014
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

In web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Image Versioning">
      <match url="(.*).png" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ver=20140320" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```